# Create a set of image files from a byte matrix

Tags: java, image, file, bufferedimage, imagej

As I wrote in the title I would like to understand how to create some images from an array that contains bytes. This is what has been written so far

```
        BufferedImage arrayImage[] = new BufferedImage [depthV];
        int arrayIndex = 0;
        for (int z = 0; z < depthV; z++)
        {
            byte byteToImg[] = new byte [widthV*heightV];
            for (int x = 0; x < widthV; x++) 
            {
                for (int y = 0; y < heightV; y++) 
                {
                     byteToImg[x + y] = data3D[0][z][y][x];
                }
            }
            ByteArrayInputStream byteIn = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteToImg);
            BufferedImage finalImage= null;
            try {
                finalImage = ImageIO.read(byteIn);
            } catch (IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            arrayImage[arrayIndex]=finalImage;
            arrayIndex++;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayImage.length; i++) 
        {
            File outputfile = new File("./Resources/tmp/image"+i+".jpg");
            try {
                ImageIO.write(arrayImage[i], "jpg", outputfile);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

The Java function ends with a java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: image == null!
What is my error? How I can avoid this issue? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Please post the full exception. Especially important here would be in which line the exception was thrown.

Comment: I can't post all the exception,it's too long. There is the interested line of code:       

ImageIO.write(arrayImage[i], "jpg", outputfile);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [SCIFIO](http://scif.io/) library, bundled with [ImageJ](http://imagej.net/), can do this easily:

```
import io.scif.gui.AWTImageTools;
...
byte[] bytes = new byte[width * height];
...
boolean signed = false;
BufferedImage bi = AWTImageTools.makeImage(bytes, width, height, signed);
```

The source code for that method is [here](https://github.com/scifio/scifio/blob/scifio-0.22.0/src/main/java/io/scif/gui/AWTImageTools.java#L107-L120) (which calls [here](https://github.com/scifio/scifio/blob/scifio-0.22.0/src/main/java/io/scif/gui/AWTImageTools.java#L315-L340), which calls [here](https://github.com/scifio/scifio/blob/scifio-0.22.0/src/main/java/io/scif/gui/AWTImageTools.java#L651-L732)).

But actually you don't need to use `BufferedImage` at all if you use SCIFIO and/or ImageJ. See [this tutorial](https://github.com/scifio/scifio-tutorials/blob/c67af787dd728642b5f39dfdb25c3bd4cbab7bb1/core/src/main/java/io/scif/tutorials/core/T1dSavingImagePlanes.java) for an example of how to write out image planes.

SCIFIO is available from the [ImageJ Maven repository](http://maven.imagej.net/). The relevant `pom.xml` snippets are:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>imagej.public</id>
        <url>http://maven.imagej.net/content/groups/public</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
...
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.scif</groupId>
    <artifactId>scifio</artifactId>
    <version>0.22.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do `ImageIO.read` to create an image from a byte array.
What works is this:

```
public class ByteRasterImage extends BufferedImage {

    private static final ColorSpace cs = ColorSpace.getInstance(ColorSpace.CS_GRAY);
    private static int[] nBits = {8};
    private static final ColorModel colorModel = new ComponentColorModel(cs, nBits, false, false,
                                         Transparency.OPAQUE,
                                         DataBuffer.TYPE_BYTE);

    private static WritableRaster createWritableRaster(byte[] bytes, final int w, final int h) {
        final DataBufferByte db = new DataBufferByte(new byte[][] {bytes}, bytes.length);
        final ComponentSampleModel sm = new ComponentSampleModel(DataBuffer.TYPE_BYTE, w, h, 1, w, new int[] {0});
        return Raster.createWritableRaster(sm, db, new Point(0, 0));
    }

    private ByteRasterImage (WritableRaster raster) {
        super (colorModel, raster, false, null);
    }

    /**
     * Create a ByteRasterImage from the given data
     * @param bytes the data content to wrap into an image, size w * h
     * @param w the width of the image
     * @param h the height of the image
     */
    public ByteRasterImage (byte[] bytes, int w, int h) {
        this(createWritableRaster(bytes, w, h));
    }
}
```

Comment: as you suggest i've edited the code this is the new snippet: 

     ByteRasterImage finalImage = new ByteRasterImage(byteToImg,widthV,heightV);
     arrayImage[arrayIndex]=finalImage;
     arrayIndex++;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayImage.length; i++) 
    {
     File outputfile = new File("./Resources/tmp/image"+i+".jpg");
     try {
      ImageIO.write(arrayImage[i], "jpg", outputfile);
     } catch (IOException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
     }
    }
But the imageset is all black

Comment: Then you have more errors: e.g. the indexing is wrong in `byteToImg[x + y] = data3D[0][z][y][x];`: you have to multiply `y` with the width of the image.